# Angular 13: ngClass not working after ng build

Tags: angular, ng-class, angular-material-table

I have a little problem with the mat table especially with the mat row.
What i want to do: Add class "is-marked" if the row has an date.

```
<mat-row [class.is-marked]="row.date && row.date.length > 5" class="{{row.date}}" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="changeLocation('/foo/bar/'+row.object_id+'/1')"></mat-row>
```

All is working fine on my local host. But if i build the project and deploy it on my server the rows get no class although they have a date.

As a test i have also added the date as a class to check if the date is reachable at that point.
And yes... there are no date or other row information after build.

How can that be and what im doing wrong?

Unfortunately, I have had no success with several versions of ngClass.

Comment: Can you check replacing class name with `[class.isMarked]` ? without  `-` in class name `isMarked`  ?

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work :/

Comment: Maybe look at how you are calling the data, what is your change detection strategy? if you are using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` then you need to tell angular to check for data changes with `ChangeDetectorRef`  else you should use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` which should check and update on every data change [see the docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)